# How do I detect "Mouse wheel scroll" and "Window manual scroll" both differently in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am working on one project where I want to do some action when user use mouse wheel scroll and Window scroll (by scrolling scroll bar on right side)

I have come up with on solution but it does action in both manners i.e. when user scroll by mouse wheel and manually by using scroll bar on window.

Here is my code which detect mouse wheel and window scroll bar

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop){
                $( "#gear1" ).css( "-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + (r + 10) + "deg)" );
                r = r + 10;

            } else {

                $( "#gear1" ).css( "-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + (r - 10) + "deg)" );
                r = r - 10;
            }
          lastScroll = st;
});
```

I want to do diffrent action when user **scroll through mouse wheel** and user **scroll through Window scroll bar**.

I need something like this:

```
If (scroll type is Mouse wheel ){
   // Do some action
}

If (scroll type is Window scroll (Scrolling by Scrollbar on right side of browser window) ){
   // Do some action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) to detect the mousewheel movements. Here's how to use it with jQuery(code copied from the docs) :

```
$('#my_elem').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
   //...
});
```

Or, you could use the following code without using any library, :

```
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
 if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel"){
    //...
 }
})
```

and if you use the second option, the code to detect the scroll without the mousewheel would be :

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    //...
});
```

Comment: Please refer the question I have made some changes in question and also explained that How I want a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture `mousewheel` event and prevent its default, which should prevent `scroll` from occuring if you use the mouse wheel. Then handle `scroll` for the other case. Be aware that different browsers/OSes/inputdevices handle `mousewheel` very differently. I think [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) tries to normalise it, however not by device but by max input, so YMMV.

Example:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(evt) {
  console.log("scroll NOT by mouse");
});

$(window).on("mousewheel", function(evt) {
  console.log("scroll by mouse");
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please refer the question I have made some changes in question and also explained that How I want a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't always get what we want. You can't distinguish the two once inside the `scroll` handler, so you need to handle the scrollwheel case before it becomes a scroll event.